# rails 4 jquery autocomplete with devise

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, devise

I've been researching the [rails-4 autocomplete gem](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete#controller) and I've been struggling trying to understand one line given in the installation. The author states that I need to add the autocomplete as following within my routes

```
resources :products do
  get :autocomplete_brand_name, :on => :collection
end
```

but for the devise controller that i need to add it to, I don't see a clear way to add that to it.

**My Routes**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations"}
```

any thoughts as to how I should be handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out. I created my own controller called suggestions

Controller

```
class SuggestionsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :school, :name
end
```

Routes

```
resources :suggestions do
  get :autocomplete_school_name, :on => :collection
end
```

View

```
<div>
  <%= f.label :school %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :school, autocomplete_school_name_suggestions_path %>
</div>
```